# CSGO Auto hotkey

Tags: steam, autohotkey, counter-strike-go-overwatch

Can someone get VAC banned for using the auto hotkey? ( i.e Bhop script)
I've seen a lot of people using it on community servers and I was wondering if it would be possible doing that on a VAC secured server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears the majority of players say that autohotkey won't get you banned, however, it possible that you may get "overwatch banned."

There's a bunch of threads on Steam and other communities that discuss this, such as [this one](https://steamcommunity.com/app/730/discussions/0/626329820697899848), where a user stated:

> AHK wont get you a vac ban cause it doesn't mess with the games files... also you aren't injecting anything. BUT if people report you ingame it may get you a overwatch review (bunnyhop) though if its for buying its highly doubtful.

Another person said on the same thread:

> AHK won't get you banned. I use it to rebind keys for music/volume and auto clicking (for Lounge betting, dang queue...). Had CSGO for over a year and never any issues.
>
> I would agree with everyone else, however, that you could easily get Overwatch banned if you're using a variant to increase your performance (such as a recoil, Bhop, or some other performance enhancing script).

A [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/33wfkq/can_i_get_vac_ban_from_bhop_script/) post coincides with the Steam thread:

> you cannot be banned for using autohotkey to jump script. you can however be overwatch banned for it. also, just because you cannot be vac banned for using it doesn't mean it's not cheating. bhopping isn't as useful in go as other cs games but it still gives you a speed boost and therefore an advantage. if you can learn to bhop without a script, that'd be best for you

So it appears that if you use AHK to give yourself an advantage in actual game play, you could be subject to an overwatch review, and possibly banned. It does not appear that VAC picks up on AHK usage.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Since AHK or the like don't inject anything into the game client, it won't be detected by VAC. But it would still be cheating if used for bhop or recoil control. Which means it could get you a ban in Overwatch. Same goes for "any similar scripting" employed using the tools provided for keyboards such as Logitech G510 or mice such as SteelSeries Sensei etc. Bottomline is, as long as you set up scripting that Overwatch judges would see as cheating, you'll risk getting an Overwatch ban. Now even more so that Valve is using heuristics to highlight inhuman behaviour.